# BlockPoolSliceScanner pool does not stop

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, cloudera

When Hadoop datanode is started the BlockPoolSliceScanner keeps pooling for every 5 seconds and doesn't stop.

How do i resolve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bug was fixed with https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HDFS-3194. You can resolve the problem by upgrading the cluster to a version of Hadoop that incorporates this patch.